# How do I get Bundler gem to work without doing /bin/bash --login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, bash

I've been following a lot of instructions on how to fix my Rails installation without really understanding everything. I can create a new Rails app now, but only if I type

```
/bin/bash --login
```

in the terminal first. If I don't do that first, the

```
rails new
```

command fails when it gets to the part with

```
bundle install
```

This is the first line of my error message I get when it fails:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:243:in `bin_path': can't find gem bundler (>= 0) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

Is there a path setting or something I can fix so I can make a new rails app in a virgin terminal window? Also, what does bin/bash --login do? It doesn't change the command prompt, and I thought I already logged in when I entered my password to start Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use:

```
rails <version> new <appname>
```

... where `<version>` is the Rails version you wish to use (e.g. `_4.2.0_`) and `<appname>` is the name of the app you wish to create.  Make sure you are at the root of your workspace when you run this command.

`/bin/bash --login` will invoke Bash as a non-interactive shell and execute commands from `/etc/profile`.  After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior. See detailed documentation [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files).  So, when you run this, it is possible that you are setting some environment variables when you do this which allow your Rails app to be created.

Comment: That command works, but still only after I do `/bin/bash --login`. I had Rails working before and I never had to use that command, but when I upgraded Ruby I did it the wrong way so I reinstalled all of my gems and now I need to do that `/bin/bash --login` for Bundler to work. How do I figure out what environment variables are being set by it so that I can make them permanent and avoid the `/bin/bash --login` necessity?

Comment: What am I looking for?

Comment: Can you post sanitized versions of the two files (`/etc/profile` and first file in next group)?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by sanitized. [/etc/profile](http://hastebin.com/icareyuceq.bash) [~/.bash_profile](http://hastebin.com/yikicarixi.bash)

Comment: So post the contents of those two files.  By sanitized, I mean, make sure you are not posting sensitive information like passwords.

Comment: Those are links to the contents of those files on hastebin

Comment: It looks like bash_profile runs two more scripts.  One approach is to capture the output of `printenv` before executing /bin/bash and then cpaturing afterwards and diffing them to see what has changed.

Comment: Other than `PATH=...` being different, a whole bunch of stuff was present in the after `printenv` that was not present in the before `printenv` . [Here is a link](http://hastebin.com/ipavevipeb.js) with the different `PATH=` values and the lines that appeared only after '/bin/bash --login'

Comment: It looks to me like `rvm` is not installed correctly.  You may want to consider reinstalling it.  Not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: Would I reinstall my gems, too?